google sheets if- condition wrong evaluation as false
In my googele sheet the condition IF(A1-SUM(B1:E1)=0.01,TRUE,FALSE) evaluates "false" although A1 is 5 and the sum B1:E1 is 4.99. I'm trying for hours, some helpful thoughts would really be appreciated :)
see link below
Greetings, Kodi
google sheet


A possible case of floating point scenario which can cause this; You may try:
=IF(round(A1-SUM(B1:E1),2)=0.01,TRUE,FALSE)



Maaaan, I really didn't see that one coming, I tried for hours and was casting doubt on even my basic excel/sheets skills :/ No solution from chat GPT either, said formula is fine, should work. So thank you very much!!!!
